# Is it posible to find a derivative of the mean function of Gaussian process regression?

Tags: gaussian-process, matrix-inverse

The mean function $\hat{\mu}(x_*)$ of GPR is
$k(x_*, X)(k(X, X) + \sigma^2_w I)^{-1}Y$
where $k(\cdot, \cdot)$ is a kernel matrix or vector of appropriate size and is parametrized by some hyperparmeters $\theta$. 
$k(x_*, X)$ is a row vector with $n$ elements and $k(X, X)$ is an $n$ by $n$ matrix where $n$ is the number of training data $X$.

My question is that is it posible to find a partial derivative of $\hat{\mu}(\cdot)$ wrt hyperparmeter $\theta$?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this useful [resource](http://www.mit.edu/~wingated/stuff_i_use/matrix_cookbook.pdf). It has lots of matrix identities, including a formula for the derivative of products of matrices and the inverse of a matrix. It's going to be messy, but presumably the derivative exists if the kernel functions are differentiable.

Why are you interested in this derivative?